# Are there example knox Hive ODBC/JDBC queries via curl?

Tags: curl, hive, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform, knox-gateway

I've looked at a couple of sites:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/knox/site/books/knox-0-9-1/user-guide.html

Only has a java example. There are also some examples for hbase but they are not using SQL.

This site on HiveWebInterface, says it is removed as of Hive 2.2.0.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveWebInterface

I am working on Hortonworks HDP 2.5.0

I'd just like to issue simple SELECT or DDL statements and see if I can run them via curl.

This has me wondering if ODBC/JDBC interface via knox uses the same http interface. I do know that ODBC/JDBC are on http. The ODBC mechanism is https. The jdbc connection uses a knox http url.

So, it must be possible to simulate querying hive using curl via knox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebHCat](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+UsingWebHCat). An example of using Knox with WebHCat (with cURL) can be found in the [user docs](http://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-11-0/user-guide.html#WebHCat+via+cURL)

e.g.

```
curl -i -k -u guest:guest-password 'https://localhost:8443/gateway/sandbox/templeton/v1/status'
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks. But there is not SQL example there though.